# Default library used by shell

Tags: linux, shell

I recently came across a question regarding linux OS. The question was MCQ and is as below:

```
By default the shell uses  _________ library.
a)read
b)readline
c)processline
```

What is the answer for this one? I do not remember the fourth option given with the MCQ. I did google for the answer, but was not able to figure it out.

Comment: You could have answered yourself this question faster googling it instead of coming to SO

Comment: Technically none are right, since the question doesn't specify *which* shell.

Answer (score 0):

By default it uses `readline` library.
Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-103-1/

Comment: That would be true if the question was about Bash but for generic "the shell" there is no well-defined correct answer.